A non-example of the amalgamation property in 2-groups
Q1. I am aware that fixing p, the class of finite p-groups does not form an amalgamation class, but I am having difficulty explicitly working out the details of the following example.
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}, \ 2 | \ k$ but $k \neq 2^m$. Consider $G = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^k$, where $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = \{[0], [1]\} = \{0, 1\}$. Let $G_{1}$ be the semidirect product $G \rtimes_\psi \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\psi$ such that $$\psi: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \text{ Aut}(G), \ \psi(0) = \psi_0 \text{ and } \psi(1) = \psi_1$$ where $\psi_0 = \text{ identity automorphism, and } \psi_1(g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4, ...., g_{k - 1}, g_{k}) = (g_2, g_1, g_4, g_3, ..., g_{k}, g_{k - 1})$, where $$g_i \in G \text{ with 1 in the ith place of the } k \text{-tuple and 0 in the other positions.}$$
Then, $G_1$ is of exponent 4. For instance, the element $$((1, 0, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0), 1)$$ is of order 4.
Let $G_2$ be the semidirect product $G \rtimes_{\psi'} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\psi'$ such that $$\psi': \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \text{ Aut}(G), \ \psi'([0]) = \psi_0 \text{ and } \psi'([1]) = \psi'_1$$ where $\psi'_1(g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4, g_5, ...., g_{k - 1}, g_{k}) = (g_1, g_3, g_2, g_5, g_4, ..., g_{k - 2}, g_{k})$.
Then, $G_2$ is also of exponent 4.
Note that $G_1 \cap G_2 = G$. (By construction, $G$ is a subgroup of both $G_1$ and $G_2$ of index 2, and $G_1 \neq G_2$).
Let $h \in G_1, G_2$ be the $(k+1)$-tuple, $h = ((0,...,0),1)$.
Now, assume an amalgam $G_0$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$ exists. Then, there exist monomorphisms $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$ as shown below

such that $\beta_1 \circ \alpha_1 (g) = \beta_2 \circ \alpha_2 \ \forall g \in G$. From a theorem of Otto Schreier, every amalgam of two groups can be embedded in the "free product of A and B with amalgamated subgroup H". Now, I can intuitively see why $G_0$ must have an element of order k, which means it cannot be a 2-group, but I am having some difficulty calculating this. My idea is that the composed action of $\beta_1(h)$ and $\beta_2(h)$ on elements of $G$ will lead to an element of order k, but I am not sure about this. I also want to know if the following argument is sufficient:

$G_0$ has an element of order $k$, which implies that $G_0$ of order
$k$. The key point is the action of $\beta_1(h)\beta_2(h)$ on elements
in the amalgam. $\beta_1(h)$ permutes elements as $\sigma
> (12)(34)...(k - 1 k)$ and $\beta_2$ as $\sigma' = (23)(45)...(k - 2 k
> - 1)$. The action of $\beta_1(h)\beta_2(h)$ corresponds to the permutation $(12)(34)...(k - 1 k)(23)(45)...(k - 2 \ k - 1)$, which
(on reducing it to the standard representation) is a $k$-cycle.

Q2. Alternatively, if anyone knows a simpler non-example, please let me know.
Q3. B. H. Neumann, in his paper titled "Permuational products of groups", says, "Thus one might hope that an amalgam of groups of exponent $n$ can be embedded in a group of exponent a power of $n$, but our example shows that this is not the case." If we take this for prime n, this gives a counter-example to the amalgamation property in n-groups, right?
Please let me know if anything requires clarification, and I apologise if I have written something inaccurately here.

Why can you not take $G=V_4$, $G_1,G_2\cong D_8$, and the two $G_i$ not swap the same two involutions of $G$? Then $Aut_{G_0}(G)$ must contain two different involutions, so be the whole of $S_3$. In particular, $3\mid |G_0|$?

There's a typo in the definition of $\psi_1'$, right? $g_5$ should be $g_4$? Does the cycle continue $(g_1,g_3,g_2,g_4,g_5,g_7,g_6,g_8,\dots)$? Also, your paragraph beginning "Let $h\in G_1,G_2$ be the ..." cuts off halfway.

@AlexKruckman $\psi_1$' should swap $g_2$ and $g_3$, $g_4$ and $g_5$, and so on. Hence, the cycle would go as $(g_1, g_3, g_2, g_5, g_4, g_7, g_6, g_9, g_8, ...).$ And thank you for pointing that out, I've finished the sentence.

@DavidA.Craven That should work; I just didn't think of it. Thank you very much!
